# What is sqlexecutive in Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

What is the "sqlexecutive" process?

Can I run it under sql2005 or sql2008 and is it available in the sqlexpress version?

Is it somehow connected with mssqlagent?

When I want to create backup of DB, should I care about stopping it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you hear that term? (The context you heard it in may help understand what you're asking). IIRC it's an old MS SQL Server component, I don't even think its part of any modern version of SQL Server.

In any case, you shouldn't be stopping **any** SQL Server components to back up SQL Server databases - use either a SQL Server aware backup process or use the backup routines available in SQL Server itself to create a backup file, then backup that file.

Comment: I found it in some old backup script as a service name

Comment: Then I'd say its the old component that I'm thinking about. Not relevant in SQL 2005/2008. As I say though you shouldn't be stopping services as part of a SQL Server DB backup anyway.

Answer (score 1):

SQLexecutive was one of the pre-SQL Server 2000 services used for managing scheduled tasks and alerts.

You may have seen it in a few older scripts if backups were set to be performed by NT server Administrator Tools (instead of SQL server).  Part of that would involve stopping and restarting the SQL services:  mssqlserver & sqlexecutive   [Here's more info.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/162294)

The only way this would still be relevent is if you were running SQL Server 6.5 or 7